# Comment traduire « blindsided » (figuré, informel) suivant un changement ou une information ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, langage-informel

> I was **blindsided** and I’m still shocked and saddened by... ([montrealgazette](https://montrealgazette.com/entertainment/television/lisa-laflamme-blindsided-after-being-dumped-by-ctv-national-news/wcm/9c50af3c-f607-42f7-9916-e6fc337f51e3))

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blindside) dit « to surprise unpleasantly » ; [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blindside) le classe au figuré et informel.

Quelle traduction convient le mieux dans ce genre de contexte ?

Answer (score 1):

L'expression la plus proche qui me vient à l'esprit est :

> J'ai été **pris au dépourvu** et...

Aussi : **pris de court**.

Comment: Penses-tu avoir besoin d'un adverbe en plus pour connoter avec plus de force l'aspect négatif et si oui, lequel ?

Comment: *J'ai été salement pris au dépourvu.*